# What is log-likelihood?

Tags: math, statistics, terminology

What is Log-likelihood?

An example would be great.

Comment: @anon, you can post your question on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @nick - he shouldn't, mathoverflow is research-level only
http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatquestions

Comment: @AB, "research level"? I didn't notice that "detail" :)

Comment: This question is actually not that bad. I'm not sure why it was closed so quickly.  He clearly doesn't know what a log-likelihood function is and is looking for a simple example.  The top google results are actually pretty bad / confusing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only reason to use the log-likelihood instead of the plain old likelihood is mathematical convenience, because it lets you turn multiplication into addition.  The plain old likelihood is P(parameters | data), i.e. assuming your data is fixed and you vary the parameters of your model.  Maximizing this is one way to do parameter estimation and is known as [maximum likelihood.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood)

Comment: I agree that this is probably what the question is about.  On notation: the likelihood is typically denoted p(data|params) or L(params|data). The object p(params|data) is the posterior.

Answer (score 6):

> **Log-likelihood ratio**
>
> A likelihood-ratio test is a
>   statistical test relying on a test
>   statistic computed by taking the ratio
>   of the maximum value of the likelihood
>   function under the constraint of the
>   null hypothesis to the maximum with
>   that constraint relaxed. If that ratio
>   is Λ and the null hypothesis holds,
>   then for commonly occurring families
>   of probability distributions, −2 log Λ
>   has a particularly handy asymptotic
>   distribution. Many common test
>   statistics such as the Z-test, the
>   F-test and Pearson's chi-square test
>   can be phrased as log-likelihood
>   ratios or approximations thereof.

http://www.knowledgerush.com/kr/encyclopedia/Log-likelihood_ratio/